# Create a Record array from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

Given a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
dict_data = [
    {'name': 'r1', 'interval': [1800.0, 1900.0], 'bool_condition': [True, False]},
    {'name': 'r2', 'interval': [1600.0, 1500.0], 'bool_condition': [False]},
    {'name': 'r3', 'interval': [1400.0, 1600.0], 'bool_condition': [True]}
]
```

I would like to create a record array from the dictionaries data.
But when I try the following I get `ValueError`

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([
('name', np.str_, 50), ('interval', np.float64, (2,)),
    ('bool_condition', np.bool)
])
values = [tuple(val.values()) for val in dict_data]
arr = np.rec.array(values, dtype=dt)
```

Error: 
`ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence`

I would like to know how could I have a more correct `dtype` and then create the record array from the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very convenient to do that with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) :

```
 In [247]: pd.DataFrame(dict_data)[['name','interval','bool_condition']].to_records(False)

Out[247]: 
rec.array([('r1', [1800.0, 1900.0], [True, False]),
 ('r2', [1600.0, 1500.0], [False]), ('r3', [1400.0, 1600.0], [True])], 
          dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('interval', 'O'), ('bool_condition', 'O')])
```

`['name','interval','bool_condition']` ensure the order of the fields.

Comment: But this has thrown out all the dtypes!

Comment: Yes. but since list and str are not aligned data, there is no performance issues here. so the dtype is IMHO not very important.

Comment: I think the fact that `interval` is aligned is sufficient reason

Comment: Is there a numpy implementation of this without using Pandas?

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that the iteration of a dictionary does not preserve the order. You can see this by looking at `print values[0]` which gives `([1800.0, 1900.0], [True, False], 'r1')` if I use your code.

Rather use

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([
    ('name', np.str_, 50),
    ('interval', np.float64, (2,)),
    ('bool_condition', np.bool)
])
values = [
    tuple([val['name'], val['interval'], val['bool_condition']])
    for val in dict_data
]
arr = np.rec.array(values, dtype=dt)
```

Another thing is that the `bool_condition` in your data is a list and not just a boolean. So you might want to change your dtype to:

```
dt = np.dtype([
    ('name', np.str_, 50),
    ('interval', np.float64, (2,)),
    ('bool_condition', list)
])
```

Comment: Note that `list` is just translated into `np.object_` here